# What is "Edit Mode" in swift in the context of TableViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, editmode

I have been messing around with [EditMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editmode) in swift `TableViews` for a bit am looking for some clarification about it. What exactly does entering EditMode do? I know that it allows you to delete and move elements in a `TableView` but I also noticed that other functions of a `TableView` are limited when `isEditing` is set to true. For instance, if you tap a cell the `didSelectRow` function does not trigger. Is this an intended behavior of activating EditMode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `didSelectRow` did not trigger is because the variable `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` is set to false by default. By setting it to true I fixed my problem.